# how build a hash table stored object in C#?

Tags: c#, hashtable

I wanted build hash table in C#

Example:

1--->"Word"---->12,

number -1- reference to "Word" and string "Word" reference to number -12-

Comment: Lol I'm sorry but ... what?

Comment: var dic = Dictionary<int, KeyValuePair<string, int>>(); dic[dic.Count] = new KeyValuePaur("word", 12); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really?

```
    Hashtable MyHashTable = new Hashtable();
    MyHashTable.Add(1, "word");
    MyHashTable.Add("word", 12);

    // to access 12
    int MyInt = (int)MyHashTable["word"];
```

Comment: Is the form of hash table Such as 1--->"Word"---->12 , if yes how access to 12.

Comment: Can I stored array replace  (1,"word") in (1,"array"),array content {12,word}, if can ,how access to element array?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  Could you try explaining what you want with pseudo code  (pretend code)?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Hashtable hash = new Hashtable();
 hash.Add(1, "Word");
 hash.Add("Word", "12");
 int value = (int)hash[hash[1]];
 System.Console.WriteLine(value);
```

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more? What do you mean to store value?

Comment: You can store in hash all keys/value pairs you need in hash, does it solve your task?

Comment: You can try to access             System.Console.WriteLine("{0}", hash[hash[1]]);

Comment: Can you explain more, what is "{0}", hash[hash[1]]" .

Comment: {0} tell that I display fier parameter after comma, hash[hash[1]].

Comment: You can display like this too:             System.Console.WriteLine(hash[hash[1]]);